# Cakephp with Adobe Muse CC

Tags: cakephp, adobe, muse

I'm in a new project and I want to know if I can combine Adobe Muse CC with Cakephp and how :

I explain :

My partner want design his website with this software and as I see, Adobe Muse generate .html, .css and .js files. Now if we want a dynamic wesite with database etc... like a blog  or social network, I have to code in PHP and I'd like o use Cake.

Now is it possible to design the website in Adobe Muse  and put it in CakePHP ? And if not do you know other editor that can make tis possible ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked out, Adobe Muse generate html and css files, but it is hard work to combine the two elements.